# Problema al validar un campo de registro en mi login de wordpress

Tags: javascript, mysql, wordpress, postgresql

Tengo un problema en el cual no eh podido poder lograr una validación de campo de registro contra una base de datos de postgresql en mi pagina de wordpress

wordpress maneja un tipo de base de datos mysql en la cual ya eh podido lograr que el dato que registro  se guarde en esta.

pero este campo al introducirlo me gustaría que se validara contra otro de mi base de datos postgree

el campo en si es un id  y este campo tiene existencia en mi base de datos de postgresql lo que yo quiero es que al inducirlo este valide si este campo existe en worpress y si es así luego se guarde en la base de datos por defecto  al contrario si no que me mande error.

esta es la validacion por defecto que eh creado en user.php en worpress

```
function username_exists( $cedula ) {
if ( $user = get_user_by( 'login', $cedula ) ) {
    return $user->ID;
}
return false;
}
```

la conexión de mi base de datos de postgresql funciona en wordpress eh hecho pruebas y me trae los datos puedo imprimirlos pero no logro entender  como hacer esta función que logre validar si los datos que existen en postgresql  antes de guardar en mysql.

campomysql=id_ced

campopostgresql=id_ced

Comment: la validación es al actualizar un usuario?

Comment: la validación  la ara al introducir el dato id en el input text  en el registro de usuario en ese punto al aceptar los datos debería validar si el id  existe

Comment: tendrías que validarlo con el filter [registration_errors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors) , desde [un custom field que agregas al form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form), hay un [tutorial en el codex  WP](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form) que te puede ayudar

Comment: me fije que el campo de registro ya yo lo agregue el  existe en el form y guarda los datos , pero yo quiero que este campo se valide contra mi otra base de datos con alguna función

Comment: si estás editando el core vas a perder los cambios en el próximo parche de seguridad ( los minor version reciben parches automáticos ), la onda es usar los filters y actions desde functions.php del custom theme o child-theme.

Comment: eso no lo sabia gracias por esta info es importante